# Safari - password request every time for Javascript module

Tags: javascript, apache

When including a Javascript module i.e:

```
<script src="js/test.js" type="module" crossorigin></script>
```

Safari is asking me for the page password every time I load the page even if I select to remember the password.

The password has been added using Apache and `AuthType Basic`.

How can I get Safari to remember the password?

Comment: Try seeing if your permissions are correct on all folders. Maybe it didn't propagate recursively? My guess is that when you're trying to load the js file from `js/*` its asking you to authenticate.

Comment: The problem is it asking for a password so of course it has propagated. The JS file loads fine if it is not a module, only then is the password not remembered, and note this does not happen in Firefox.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue in my webapp and didn't succeed, i.e. Safari successfully remembers the password with the js string above (with and without `type="module"`).
Maybe you have another dependencies that can impact Safari's behavior? Anyway I tried the empty JS itself on Safari version 14.0 (15610.1.28.1.9, 15610). So please provide more details.

Comment: Like kli said it worked for them, is it possible this is a machine dependent error? Did you try on a different machine? I wouldn't be surprised if Apple security is causing unexpected behavior.

Comment: Seems to be fixed in the latest Safari version.